# How do I find this function the growth rate based on the big O notation?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, big-o

How do I find this function the growth rate based on the big O notation?

```
for(i=1; i*i<n; i=i+1)
    for(j=1; j<=i; j=j+1)
```

Comment: Approx O(n) or O(sqrt(n)^2)

Comment: it will take .. O(log(n!))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following

when `i=1`,
innerloop runs 1 time

outloop `i=2`,
innerloop runs 2 times

outloop `i=3`,
innerloop runs 3 times

outloop `i=4`,
innerloop runs 4 times

....

outloop `i=sqrt(n)-1`,
innerloop runs `sqrt(n)-1` times, the loop terminates here

Lest assume that `n` is a perfect square

```
==> f(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + sqrt(n) - 1 = (sqrt(n) - 1 )/2 x ( sqrt(n) - 1 + 1)

==> f(n) = ( (sqrt(n)^2)/2 - sqrt(n)/2 

==> O( sqrt(n)^2)/2 - sqrt(n)/2 ) = O( n - sqrt(n) )

==> O( n - sqrt(n) )
==> O( n )
```

So it approximately  takes **O(n)**